# Add fonts / Adobe / PlayonLinux?

Tags: fonts, playonlinux, adobe

Can I add all the fonts that I have in my Ubuntu system into Adobe Photoshop and Adobe Illustrator with PlayOnLinux?

Both Photoshop and Illustrator runs great; however,both Adobe software has the basic Adobe fonts.They do not read my fonts that I have in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I got the revelation !

I was messing around with different font folders.

Then I had added one font to this directory:

Home > PlayOnLinux > Wine > linuxx86 > 2.22 > share > wine > fonts

It Works! 
Now I have my 3,000 fonts with Adobe Photoshop and Adobe Illustrator.

You just have to Log Out and Log Back In, as the 90's with Macs.

.... Hope this helps humans !